# what is the best practice for modeling relationships with sails and mongo

Tags: mongodb, sails.js

I have this situation and I'd like to know what is the best practice here when modeling my data.

I'm using Sails and Mongo and I can't quite tell from the docs what to do.

I have User, a user can create Vendors, Vendors can create Pages, pages have Templates.

My question is this, when I'm making a user, should I be populating a vendors array with vendor ID's or should I only be relying on a user id reference in the vendor collection. The same logic follows further - should my vendors' pages be stored in a pages array in the vendor object, or simply as a vendor field in the page object.

I had the same dilemma when I was using mongoose and the docs didn't make it too clear either:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html See 'Refs to Children'

> We may find however, if we use the aaron object, we are unable to get
>   a list of the stories. This is because no story objects were ever
>   'pushed' onto aaron.stories.
>
> There are two perspectives here. First, it's nice to have aaron know
>   which stories are his.

```
aaron.stories.push(story1);
aaron.save(callback);
Person.findOne({ name: 'Aaron' }) .populate('stories') // only works
if we pushed refs to children .exec(function (err, person) {   if
(err) return handleError(err);   console.log(person); })
```

> It is debatable that we really want two sets of pointers as they may
>   get out of sync. Instead we could skip populating and directly find()
>   the stories we are interested in.

```
Story
.find({ _creator: aaron._id })
.exec(function (err, stories) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  console.log('The stories are an array: ', stories);
})
```

So this is what Mongoose says and I'm not too clear how to proceed.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no MongoDB expert but I would agree with the second statement and in your case just have the user id reference in the vendor model and same with vendors and pages.

It does depend on your use-cases though, will you often have a case where you have a user and you need to find all the vendors that user created? Is time important in that case? Because the user id solution will be slower then (without caching), but as mentioned you don't have to worry about data integrity and you will use less space.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think the possibility of ruined data integrity is a much bigger headache than the potential performance loss. Will stick with approach 2. Which is also automatic in SANE due to the blueprint, so awesome. I have that working with 0 lines server code.